# Error `ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'processor': expected token ':', got '}'` when trying to bring up Airflow 1.10.6 in kubernetes

Tags: python, jinja2, airflow

I'm trying to bring up a new instance of Airflow, version 1.10.6, in a `Kubernetes` cluster but I keep running into the below error on the scheduler pod (copied the error up to what seemed most crucial).

```
    self.name, self.filename)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ':', got '}'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 25, in <module>
    from airflow.configuration import conf
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    settings.initialize()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/settings.py", line 374, in initialize
    LOGGING_CLASS_PATH = configure_logging()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/logging_config.py", line 68, in configure_logging
    raise e
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/logging_config.py", line 63, in configure_logging
    dictConfig(logging_config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/config.py", line 795, in dictConfig
    dictConfigClass(config).configure()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/config.py", line 566, in configure
    '%r: %s' % (name, e))
ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'processor': expected token ':', got '}'
```

Has anybody else run into this? I've never used jinja directly so I'm struggling to weed through my Airflow files to find what could be causing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first guess is that it's likely that you simply have a syntax error in your config file.

Comment: You were right, I used an older configuration file I had from another environment and it works. Thank you!